# stm32f030cct6 SWDIO is pulldown when i try to program and my STLINK can't find the target

Tags: stm32, stm32f0

I am trying to program a stm32f030cct6 with a ST-Link v2.

When I try to connect using CubeProgramer it says: "Target not found".

I connect to NREST, CLK and SWDIO. I'm measuring the signals with an oscilloscope SWDIO is in PullDown when it should be in PullUp, as it says in the datasheet.

Note that the clock takes some more time to start toggle, about 200 ms

[oscillogram of switching the device on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDn44.jpg)

I try to connect NRST via the button to GND. I press the button and then start "Connect" and release the button after about a second to do a "Mass Erase" and nothing changes.

I don't know what could be the error. Any hint appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: could be the program that's already in MCU repurposes the pin before debugger connects to it, among other possible problems. Connect using cubeprogrammer while physically holding reset button (reset permanently pulled low). It's called "connect under reset". Then you should be able to mass erase. Also, please, include picture into the post